# UIPickerView in UITableViewCell showing behind next Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a tableview with a number of custom cells.  The problem I am having is that the cell with the pickerview is 'bleeding' behind the neighboring cell.

Once I push another view controller and pop back, the neighboring cell is properly opaque until I manipulate the picker, at which point the issue materializes again.

The cell is, in fact, opaque.  I have set it as such in both the storyboard and code.  I have also tried `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

[image: UIPickerView values bleeding to next cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `clipsToBounds` property to `true` to each cell in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You can set this property in the Storyboard if you are using prototypes cells.

Comment: adding `clipsToBounds = true` did the trick.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information. 
But if I understand correctly, you should hide the cell that contains the picker and only show it when the user will input. 
Here is a tutorial on how to hide the cell, like the calendar iOS app does.

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: This is a neighboring cell and is visible at all times.